# Bar chart plotted on world map

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, webgl, cesiumjs

Is there any way to plot bar charts on world map. The world map can be of 3D view like a Globe or 2D view. It should be also be able to zoom into street level. Could someone give me some ideas and examples about this?

I already found out: http://threegraphs.com/charts/sample/world/.

It would be really helpful if similar examples can be  provided.

Comment: Also interested in knowing about this.

Comment: I'm interested as well, especially in whether there's a way to do this in python...

Answer (score 5):

A similar Cesium demo is hosted here:

http://cesiumjs.org/demos/d3.html

A coworker of mine made this.  It uses [Polylines](https://cesiumjs.org/2013/04/22/Robust-Polyline-Rendering-with-WebGL/) sticking up vertically from a black-and-white globe.  The [source code](https://github.com/abwood/d3cesium) is on GitHub.

*EDIT 2015-Mar-03: Updated links.*

Comment: These links are now broken. Any chance you can edit with the new location?